# Writing HQL Query for ManyToOne Association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Hii,
I have two entities with bidirectional association.

Project.java

```
class Project{

    int project_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="project")
    private Set<Users> projectsUsers = new HashSet<Users>();

    //getters and setters and other fields

}
```

Users.java

```
class Users{ 

    int id;
    int userId;
    int project_id 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id") 
    private Project project; 

    //getters and setters and other fields

}
```

I want to write an HQL query which retrieves the list of projects associated with a particular userId.

I was writing some thing like this which didnt work.

```
from Project P where P.projectsUsers.userId=1
```

When trying to execute this I am getting a exception "illegal attempt to dereference collection"
can anyone of you please help me in solving the problem?

Thanks in Advance

With Regards
Phani Kumar

Comment: a) please don't format you code using HTML and / or `>` quotes. Select a code block and use the icon with the curly braces b) The JPA query language is JPQL, not HQL. One of the tags in your question is wrong, which one is it?

Comment: Actually I am working this part of code on Spring-MVC.So I thought that I may get a better workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, "the list of projects associated with a particular userId" doesn't make sense since you have one-to-many/many-to-one relation so that each user can be associated with no more than one project.

The query to retrieve that project is as follows:

```
SELECT u.project FROM users u WHERE u.userId = ?
```

Comment: I have done a work around for this,but anyway  according my table it is one user can be associated with n no of projects.In users table the combination of userId and project_id is unique.

Comment: BTW according to the solution you have given I figured out a new way to solve the problem.Thank you very much